# Should I use pressure treated wood in a basement?

Tags: framing, pressure-treated, built-ins

Home inspector once told me my basement has a slightly high moisture reading.

No mold, dampness or musty smell.

I am building an entertainment built-in out of lumber and MDF.

Should I use pressure treated lumber where the wood will sit in contact with the concrete floor/foundation? The rest will be standard 2x4 lumber.

Comment: It can't hurt.  Will you be leaving the floor bare concrete?

Comment: Yes, at least that was my initial intention

Comment: I would absolutely not use any material susceptible to rot (such as plain ordinary construction lumber)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'are trying to save money you could use regular lumber with sill seal, then the wood will not come in contact with the concrete. https://preview.tinyurl.com/yc5zzslh The URL takes you to a preview first and then provides a new link.

Comment: A strip of plastic sheeting would probably work also. You may want to caulk the holes of whatever (galvanized or stainless) fasteners used to attach to the slab.

Comment: A little late for the OP, I'm sure, but here I go - your house (ANY structure) that has any potential for cracking foundation/leaking roof/bad exterior paint job/etc has a potential for water infiltration. In both of the houses (90yrs and 100yrs old) where I have demo'd walls in the basement I have found at least one sill plate that was rotted out. In one of them the sill plate (from a 1980s reno) was completely composted to dirt as a result of persistent water leaking.

Answer (score 3):

Most building codes require PT wood that will be in contact with basement concrete floors. So the bottom plate of a 2x4 wall and code requires the use of fasteners (galvanized) approved for use with PT wood.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should use naturally durable (Redwood, cedar), or preservative-treated wood (AWPA U1 and M4) for sills or sleepers on a concrete or masonry slab that is in direct contact with the earth if you want to do it by the book (IBC 2304.11.2.4) and its also a wise idea.